write syscall with mmaped buffer
I work with large files and as a result of development I had to copy large files (about 10 gigabytes) in C code.
In this regard, the question arose: how effective is the combination of map()+write() (an existing file is mapped in memory and write done to an existing file)?
Will conditional Windows/macOS/Linux/*BSD handle this in a special way to optimize copying data from one file to another
Sample code that is present in my project (assume code ran on unix-like OS and all syscalls succeed, input and output are some regular files):
int main() {
    struct stat sb;
    int fdsrc, fddst;
    void *p;

    fdsrc = open("input", O_RDONLY);
    fddst = open("output", O_WRONLY);

    fstat(fdsrc, &sb);
    p = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fdsrc, 0);
    write(fddst, p, sb.st_size);

    return 0;
}

Will it be as fast as copy_file_range(2) or kinda? Is there some code in Linux/*BSD sources which handles this case?
P.S.: On linux write(2) as i know never writes more than INT_MAX bytes in one call, so in my project i use full_write() wrapper which calls write(2) until all data written or one of the syscalls fails.

have you taking any timings, resource measurements to compare ? , that'd be a good starting point before posting, also conditions at the time could impact performance, as will hardware configuration, filesystems, network ...

Is there a special reason you don't use copy_file_range function?

@Markus copy_file_range have some limitations such as:

It won't work when src and dest files are on different devices which does not support cross-fs copy.
It is much less portable than mmap+write
It is pretty new syscall in linux kernel and has issues before 5.3 (see gnulib comment)


Would an appropriate answer have a benchmark? Surely someone already made one. tl;dr: if you can't use copy_file_range, mmap+write is the second best choice, over 32 MB you won't notice the difference unless your disk is crazy fast.

The fastest method could be to mmap both the source and destination files, then use memcpy(). You'll need to truncate the destination file to the appropriate length before mapping it, since mmap() won't grow a file by itself.

But I wonder if you can map two 10GB files at once.

@Barmar, what would prevent you from doing so ?

@ticktalk Whether the process virtual memory has contiguous 10GB blocks available.

@Barmar You could do it in smaller chunks.

@IanAbbott True, similar to doing the writes in smaller chunks.

@Barmar, do you need 10gb memory (virtual or otherwise) to mmap a 10gb file ? , the file will be paged into memory as needed ?

@ticktalk You need enough contiguous virtual addresses to map it.

@Barmar, i contest that you need contiguous virtual memory

Of course you do. mmap() just returns the address of the beginning of the block, the rest of the mapped file is offsets from that address. How could it be split over several address blocks?

paging .... (this exchange of yes it does no it doesn't is distracting from the user's question), happy to take it offline

The fastest way is to use two mmaps and a memcpy (but your solution also works well as I remember). That is way faster because everything is made by the kernel, letting the memory management system, copy-on-write and buffer caching do the job. I tried it several years ago and it works much faster; now I don't know if it worth the effort. At least you are replacing loop of syscalls (which is costly) by two syscalls (or a few due to write limits).
